# gradle4.5 compile error: Cannot add task

Tags: android, gradle

I use the productFlavors

[image: i]

returns error

> Cannot add task ':app:reportSourceSetTransformTest' as a task with that name already exists.

at gradle 4.4 or earlier version doesn't have this problem.
When I updated it to gradle 4.5 yesterday, it returns error, clean project is the same problem. Why?

android studio version:3.2 canary 3

[image: e]

Comment: This happened to me too.  Still waiting for an answer...

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52257747/cannot-add-task-appreportsourcesettransformtest-as-a-task-with-that-name-alr

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the reason, I can only lower the Gradle version and the plugin version first. Gradle decreased from 4.6 to 4.4, and plugin decreased from 3.2 to 3.1.4

Comment: See if this solves your problem.  Noticed you also have a flavor named "Test" which Gradle 4.6 seems to find as a conflict.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52257747/cannot-add-task-appreportsourcesettransformtest-as-a-task-with-that-name-alr