# Cannot add task ':app:reportSourceSetTransformTest' as a task with that name already exists

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

```
Minimum supported gradle version 4.6 Current version is 4.4.
```

After updating gradle version to 4.6, am getting this error

```
Cannot add task ':app:reportSourceSetTransformTest' as a task with that name already exists.
```

How can I avoid this error. It seems like two different files have same task. But I didnot find any or explicitly define any task in my app level build.gradle file.

My project level `build.gradle` file is this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and app level `build.gradle` file is this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'
    flavorDimensions "default"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.applicationId"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.2"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
  }

dependencies {
    implementation project(':demo')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation('junit:junit:4.12')
    implementation 'com.github.ViksaaSkool:AwesomeSplash:v1.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case I had a conflict with my flavour name and new gradle plugin.
The problem was solved when I changed the names of my flavours (Production, Test) -> (production, develop)

Comment: Thank you!  That was my issue as well.  I had to change the name of my Test flavor to something else (Offline) and also had to change a Test folder to Offline where I had flavor specific classes